# GSSAPI: importing a context created on a different host

Tags: gssapi

I am learning about GSSAPI and am intrigued by the exporting/importing context feature of the API.  I am designing an application that will involve multiple processes across multiple machines.  My question, then, is: if I create a security context and export it from machine A, can I import it in a program running on machine B?  The documentation refers to an "interprocess token," but that language is somewhat vague.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? Have every token its own context.